# How to configure LXD container devices using saltstack "lxd_container.present" function?

Tags: salt-stack, lxc, lxd

I have the following **working** Salt state file which: 1) downloads an image 2) creates a container from that image and 3) adds a  nic afterwards.

These states work using the following setup:

- **salt-ssh**: *version 3004*
- **Python**: *3.9.7*
- **LXC (snapd)**: *version 5.0.0*
- **PyLXD**: *version 2.3.0*
- **Linux ubuntu**: *aarch64*

```
---
# Create Penguin Container
#---

get_focal:
  lxd_image.present:
    - name: 'focal'
    - source:
        type: simplestreams
        server: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases 
        name: '20.04'

create_penguin:
  lxd_container.present:
    - name: penguin
    - profiles: ['default']
    - source: 'focal'
    - running: true
    - devices:
    ### I want to create NIC here. ###

add_nic_card:
  cmd.run: 
    - name: |
        lxc config device add penguin eth0 nic nictype=bridged parent=br0
```

I need to combine states #2 and #3 so the nic is created simultaneously with the container.  This should be possible according to the [official documentation](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.lxd_container.html#salt.states.lxd_container.present).  However, I've not been able to get the syntax right, and the error codes aren't helpful.

I've tried numerous variations of the following:

#### variation 1

```
create_penguin:
  lxd_container.present:
    - name: penguin
    - profiles: ['default']
    - source: 'focal'
    - running: true
    - devices:
        eth0: {
          type: "nic",
          nictype: "bridged",
          parent: "br0" }
```

#### variation 2

```
create_penguin:
  lxd_container.present:
    - name: penguin
    - profiles:
      - default
    - source: 'focal'
    - running: true
    - devices:
        eth0:
          type: nic
          nictype: bridged
          parent: br0
```

**Variation 2 produces the following error:**

```
----------
          ID: create_penguin
    Function: lxd_container.present
        Name: penguin
      Result: False
     Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/state.py", line 2179, in call
                  ret = self.states[cdata["full"]](
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 149, in __call__
                  return self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1201, in run
                  return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1216, in _run_as
                  return _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1249, in wrapper
                  return f(*args, **kwargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/states/lxd_container.py", line 235, in present
                  __salt__["lxd.container_create"](
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 149, in __call__
                  return self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1201, in run
                  return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1216, in _run_as
                  return _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/modules/lxd.py", line 691, in container_create
                  container_device_add(name, dn, **dargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/modules/lxd.py", line 1431, in container_device_add
                  return _set_property_dict_item(container, "devices", device_name, kwargs)
                File "/var/tmp/.ubuntu_a31665_salt/pyall/salt/modules/lxd.py", line 3544, in _set_property_dict_item
                  raise SaltInvocationError("path must be given as parameter")
              salt.exceptions.SaltInvocationError: path must be given as parameter
     Started: 09:43:31.807609
    Duration: 5147.141 ms
     Changes:   
----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took cue from the [lxd-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/lxd-formula) and as described in documentation, we need supply a dict to `devices:` in YAML format. So, the curly brackets `{ .. }` are not required.

Following that, I found that the below syntax works fine:

```yaml
create_penguin:
  lxd_container.present:
    - name: penguin
    - profiles: ['default']
    - source: 'focal'
    - running: true
    - devices:
        eth0:
          type: nic
          nictype: bridged
          parent: br0
        # another network interface
        eth1:
          type: nic
          nictype: bridged
          parent: br0
```

For reference, my setup:

| component | version |
| --- | --- |
| Salt | 3003.3 |
| Python | 3.8.10 |
| dist | ubuntu 20.04 focal |
| lxc (apt) | 4.0.9 |
| pylxd | 2.3.1 |

And output from Saltstack (had removed `eth1` from the state):

```
----------
          ID: create_penguin
    Function: lxd_container.present
        Name: penguin
      Result: True
     Comment: 1 changes
     Started: 12:38:58.041506
    Duration: 27277.86 ms
     Changes:   
              ----------
              devices:
                  ----------
                  eth0:
                      Added device "eth0"
```

Comment: Just curious, what was your setup @sethadri_c.  I've included notes in the OP regarding mine.

Comment: I updated my setup details.

Comment: I marked you answer correct, because it seems to be the one provided in the official documentation for your version.  I still had to do a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution provides a satisfactory work around to the original post.  Instead of adding a separate stanza, I've created a profile named "natted" and added it to the container.  While it works with my version of Salt, it's a little less explicit/transparent than the "official" answer in documentation.

```
---
# Create & Start the Penguin Container
#---

penguin_create_start:
  lxd_container.present:
    - name: penguin
    - source: 'focal'
    - running: true
    - profiles: ['default', 'natted']
...
```

The profile looks something like this:

```
---
# equivalent to --> 'lxc config device add penguin eth0 nic nictype=bridged parent=br0'
#---

  config: {}
  description: Adds eth1 to 'lxdbr0' bridge
  devices:
    eth1:
      nictype: bridged
      parent: lxdbr0
      type: nic
  name: natted
```